# Unknown cause of InvalidOperationException?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a string array that I use to split output from another process. I then want to display the first element of that array in a textbox in my WPF interface. However, I receive this exception when I try to do so, any ideas of how to fix it?

```
        output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        code = p.ExitCode;
        p.WaitForExit();
        string[] result = this.output.Split(new string[] { "\n", "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        this.outputList.Add(Convert.ToDouble(result[0]));
        this.MyTextBox.Text = result[0];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The InvalidOperationException should tell you exactly which line of code caused the exception.  Put a try/catch around your code and then read the StackTrace property to get the line of code causing the problem.

```
try
{
    output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    code = p.ExitCode;
    p.WaitForExit();
    string[] result = this.output.Split(new string[] { "\n", "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    // If you are updating UI controls, make sure you are doing it only on the UI thread.  The 'Dispatcher' will make sure the code inside is run on the UI thread.
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        this.outputList.Add(Convert.ToDouble(result[0]));
        this.MyTextBox.Text = result[0];
    });
}
catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
{
    // You don't need this line, you can just put a breakpoint here to debug the problem by reading the properties of the 'ex' variable.
    this.MyTextBox.Text = $"{ex.Message}\n{ex.StackTrace}";
}
```

Comment: This is what ex says: {"The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."}

Comment: Sounds like you have a problem where you are trying to write to your UI controls on a different thread.  To make sure you are only updating these controls from the UI thread, you need to wrap it around a Dispatcher.  See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much!